# Creating a Logging Class Wrapper

Tags: python, class, decorator, python-decorators, python-3.8

I am attempting to write a quick decorator to manage logging returns of various functions. I am not super well versed in decorators so any help you can provide would be very helpful!

```
from functools import update_wrapper
from typing import Any, Optional
from logging import getLogger
from time import perf_counter
from datetime import datetime

class logger:

    def __init__(self, func:callable, response:str = "debug"):
        self.logger = getLogger()
        self.func = func
        self.response = response

        update_wrapper(self, func)

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return getattr(self, self.response)

    def debug(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.logger.debug(f"Running {__name__} with id: {id(self)} at {datetime.now()}")
        start = perf_counter()
        value = self.func(*args, **kwargs)
        end = perf_counter()
        self.logger.debug(f"""Completed {__name__} with id: {id(self)} at {datetime.now()}.
            Total Time to run: {end - start:.6f}s""")
        return value

    def info(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.logger.info(f"Running {__name__} at {datetime.now()}.")
        return self.func(*args, **kwargs)

@logger(response="debug")
def stuff(x):
    return x*x

stuff(2)
```

The error I am receiving is:

`TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'func'`,

clearly, it doesn't like the required callable and the response requirement. However, I see in all other class-based decorator setups that func needs to be called as part of the `__init__` and I have also seen you can pass decorators addition information. What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT:

The purpose of `getattr(self, self.response)` is so that the function returned by `__call__` is either the function along with the `debug` or `info` logging. This allows me to utilize the decorator @logging for both logging and debug, yet yields two different results depending on the response value specified in the decorator (i.e @logging(response="info")).

Solution:

```
class logger:

    def __init__(self, response:str = "debug"):
        self.logger = getLogger()
        self.response = response

    def __call__(self, func:callable):
        update_wrapper(self, func)
        self.func = func
        return getattr(self, self.response)

    def debug(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.logger.debug(f"Running {self.func.__name__} (type:{type(self.func)}) with id: {id(self)} at {datetime.now()}")
        start = perf_counter()
        value = self.func(*args, **kwargs)
        end = perf_counter()
        self.logger.debug(f"""Completed {self.func.__name__} with id: {id(self)} at {datetime.now()}.
            Total Time to run: {end - start:.6f}s""")
        return value

    def info(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.logger.info(f"Running {self.func.__name__} at {datetime.now()}.")
        return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: func should be an argument of call.... and the arguments of call should be rescaled some how. Could try to make an example of the desired syntax?

Comment: to see what is going on undo the @ at stuff function and after its declaration run `logger(stuff)(7)`. The error disappear. You then have to reimplement the decorator properly

Comment: @cards, i guess that is the part that confuses me. `logger(stuff)(7) ` clearly works. Doesnt the wrapper part @ create the `logger(stuff)` aspect of it? Then when you call `stuff(7)`, you are effectively making the call `logger(stuff)(7)`.

Comment: you have to keep track of the order of the "calls" of the methods in the class: fist `__init__` then `__call__`. the decorator like @ my_decorator aspects as next argument the function to be called. If the decorator takes argument @ my:decorator2(  some_args) then the next should be again a function. Take care of the order and if arguments are needed

Comment: it is the final call which will perform the decoration! So it should contains only the func as parameter (eventually **kwargs... you can test it)

Comment: @cards, I am not sure I am following perfectly. Can you clarify a bit more? Are you saying that I shouldn't be performing the `self.func` inside of the `__call__` and that what I need is to return a function from the `__call__`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what your code should do, in particular it is not clear (to me) which kind of arguments should be passed to `getattr(self, self.response)(*args, **kwargs)`. I am saying this to understand the proper workflow of the decorator.

So your code will never work. Here some possible examples of decoration:

the `__call__`way: `@logger(response="debug")`

```
class logger_1:

    def __init__(self, response:str = "debug"):
       print(response)

    def __call__(self, func):
        self.func = func
        return self # ? depends on what are you doing

    def debug(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # ...

    def info(self, *args, **kwargs):
        #... 

@logger_1(response="debug")
def stuff(x):
    return x*x
```

A level more of "abstraction":  `@logger(response="debug").('some_parameter').debug_method`

```
class logger_2:

    def __init__(self, response:str = "debug"):
       print(response)

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       self.updated_response = getattr(self, self.response)(*args, **kwargs) # just an example
       return self

    def debug_method(self, func):
       self.func = func
       # ...
       return func

    def debug(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # ...

    def info(self, *args, **kwargs):
        #... 

@logger_2(response="debug")('some_parameter').debug_method
def stuff(x):
    return x*x
```

**NB:** `logger_2(response="debug").('some_parameter').debug_method` is not taking argument because it waits to be "feed" with the target function `stuff`

These are examples of syntax which constraint the workflow, so you need to be careful when design your decorator

Comment: It looks like there were two primary issues I was having. First, I was calling function in `__init__` instead of `__call__`. Fundamentally this makes sense to me, however, every example I see of class decorators initialized the function in `__init__`.  So I am confused how most examples work.  Second, is that that I was returning a value by worrying about the args, rather than a new function.

Comment: @WolVes careful to edit! if you decorate with `__init__` then its parameter has to be the function... it depends on how many levels of "inceptions" we want:)

Comment: look at the solution I posted and see if that makes sense to you. I want to make sure you get credit for the solution on this.

Comment: that is the purpose of the response and getattr(). You will get the function debug with getattr(self, "debug"). As getattr returns the attribute assigned to the self named "debug".

Comment: @WolVes Yes! I needed to add a print statement inside the methods to see that actually that a change of behavior take place by changing parameter from "debug" to "info". Is it what you had in mind?

Comment: yep you got it! exactly!

Comment: happy to hear that. If you I should modify my answer or adding smt just leave me a comment, I will do that tomorrow. Have fun!